# Raspberry Pi and TI CC2564

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I am trying to integrate a few sensors and transfer the data via a dual mode bluetooth. I have ordered a TI CC2564 evaluation board and have a raspberry pi with me. So can anyone clarify me on this, whether I will be able to couple a R-Pi with the CC2564 to run the bluetooth stack and my application to send the data via BLE and BT classic. Bluetopia is a supported stack for CC2564, can I run it on my R-Pi. Is there any other supported BT stack.

Thanks for your time.

Regards Gaurav.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Bluetopia, but you can try [BlueZ](http://www.bluez.org) on your R-Pi, I can confirm that it is working (on Debian Wheezy) with USB BT dongle.

[BTstack](https://code.google.com/p/btstack/) is also working on CC2564 (but I couldn't make it work on R-Pi + USB BT dongle since there is some problem with libusb when using BTstack.